# Run AutoGPT in Google Colab. Chrome not reachable

Tags: google-colaboratory, chromium, chatgpt-api, autogpt

I want to run AutoGPT in Colab but fail with

```
  System: Command browse_website returned: Error: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I tested this to install Chrome like this

```
!apt-get update
!apt-get install -y chromium-browser
```

Checking

```
!whereis chromium-browser
```

tells it is in

```
 /usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

It's quite unclear to me how to debug this. Any idea. Firefox also failed

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can change the browser for Firefox in the `.env` file:

```
USE_WEB_BROWSER=firefox
```